# How to set margin/padding for x-axis values in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I built a graph using MPAndroidChart, but there is a problem - values on x-axis overlap.
[image]

Is there a way to fix it? Something like a margin between x-axis values?

Answer (score 13):

It's been a while since you've posted your question and probably by now you found your way around this problem, however, I'm posting this answer for anyone else who has faced this issue.

Setting

```
chart.getXAxis().setSpaceMin(0.5f);
```

would add space between the X-axis line and the chart itself. you can also use

```
chart.getXAxis().setSpaceMax(0.5f);
```

for adding space between the last value and the right X-axis of the chart.

Here is an example of a [normal chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfZ2k.png) and this one is a [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOtfK.png)
with min and max space of 1.5.

By the way, I'm using MPAndroidChart V3.0.2.

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm using v3.1.0. Even after setting xAxis.spaceMin = 1.5f
 xAxis.spaceMax = 1.5f,  Lowest and highest values are extending till the edges in the XAxis.  What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
 xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(int characters) //Sets the space that should be left out between the x-axis labels in characters, default: 4.
```

Comment: I have setLabelsToSkip(0) and probably it's not working together with setSpaceBetweenLabels because as I can see for setLabelsToSkip doc "This will disable the feature that automatically calculates an adequate space between the axis labels"

Comment: cant find :( therb is no method for me